# UI unresponsive in the simulator while downloading but ok on device

Tags: ios

My app downloads content from a server and recently I've noticed the GUI has gone unresponsive while the download is in progress (it used to be fine) BUT it only happens in the simulator and not on hardware.

How can there be this difference?

Its using NSURLConnection:initWithRequest: so the download is asynchronous and there's no synchronous activity going on off the main thread, or elsewhere for that matter.

What's puzzling me most is how can it can work fine on the device but not on the simulator? Are there any known problems with the simulator or differences from hardware that would account for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause - its NSLog. I was logging the data as it was being downloaded and this caused the GUI to become unresponsive until the download and thus the logging had finished.